# view git projects directly from the bare repository

Tags: git, web, wamp

I have a local server with WAMP 2.2 installed on it and I've just installed [Git Stack](http://gitstack.com/) on it to share projects with local users , now, of course i can't view the bare repository on the server,

So i need to make something like HEROKU, after the changes are pushed i want to access the projects on server directly, Just like HEROKU ..... push and view

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Git Stack comes with its own Apache to serve its managment pages. It will, by default be using port 80 just like the Apache that comes with WAMP.

You are going to have to change the port that Git Stack uses, see documentation.